# My question is about google API for fetching googlegroups.com users

Tags: google-api, google-code

What is the google API for fetching googlegroups.com users?

```
gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        })
```

My question is related to public googlegroups.com  not related to Gsuite groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find list of Members in group using google api services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891762/find-list-of-members-in-group-using-google-api-services)

Comment: Hi  Hoppeduppeanut , The given link shows for gsuite groups. My question is related to public googlegroups.com

Comment: https://groups.google.com doesnt have any API that i am aware of.